# Twig define dynamic generate variable

Tags: 8, theming

I have field names:

- field_en_image
- field_sv_image

node_lang is set as a variable in the .theme file under _preprocess_node hook.

I want to print the field dynamically in the twig template file based on the current language.

```
{{ node.["field_"~node_lang~"image"]|view }}
```

but this seems to be not working.

Comment: I think this is a general Twig question and as such off-topic. What you're looking for are [dynamic variable names in Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40177195/dynamic-variable-in-twig-example)

Comment: {% set fieldName = "field_" ~ node_lang ~ "_title" %}
{{ fieldName.value }}
{{ fieldName.view }} is not working as well

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
{% set field_name = "field_"~node_lang~"image" %}
{{ attribute(node,field_name) | view }}
```

or

```
{% set field_name = "field_"~node_lang~"image" %}
{{ attribute(content,field_name) }}
```

> If you want to access a dynamic attribute of a variable, use the
>   attribute function instead.
>
> The attribute function is also useful when the attribute contains
>   special characters (like - that would be interpreted as the minus
>   operator):
>
> ```
> {# equivalent to the non-working foo.data-foo #}
> {{ attribute(foo, 'data-foo') }}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the _context variable instead, which represent the whole accessibles variables, you can find some informations about that variable under [Macros documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/macro.html).

That snippet may help :

```
{% set language = 'fr' %}

{% set foobar = _context["field_" ~ language ~ "_foobar"] is defined ? _context["field_" ~ language ~ "_foobar"] : null %}

{{ foobar }}
```

I've wrote to you a little TwigFiddle, [check it out](https://twigfiddle.com/9fxozf) :)

Comment: I tried below, but its not displaying anything.


{% set language = 'fi' %}
{% set foobar = _context["field_" ~ language ~ "_title"] is defined ? _context["field_" ~ language ~ "_title"] : null %}
{{ foobar }}

Comment: Those fields `field_fi_title` and every "languages related" ones exists in the database ?